# How to find a window in X Window System on Linux and bring it to front?

Tags: java, linux, automated-tests, window-managers, xserver

I have a series of automated user tests of Swing GUI that use Java robot and User32 native library on Windows. With methods like `User32.INSTANCE.EnumWindows` I am able to find a window with a specific title, bring it to front and then use key-strokes to perform actions. The windows I am looking for are either other Swing Apps (running in separate JVM), PDF viewers or browsers. I have no control of those windows.

Is there a way how to do this on Linux?

My setup (can be changed if it helps, virtual machines will be used anyway):

- Ubuntu 14.04
- tightvnc server with xvnc
- IceWM window manager

Note: I am running these tests on a headless server.

Required operations:

- Find a named window (by title, to confirm something was opened)
- Bring a named window to front and focus on it (to perform keystrokes)

Comment: You can look into the `XTest` extension as well as tools like `wmctrl` and `xdotool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Etan's suggestion, I've installed wmctrl:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

And then called it from Java. For finding a named window:

```
wmctrl -l <title>
```

For getting focus:

```
wmctrl -a <title>
```

Works well even when partial title is used, therefore I could easily replace the tests written for `User32` native library.